# How do I retain the state in a web app during use of authenticator app on mobile device

Tags: web-applications, progressive-web-apps, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I have a web app that works with Google Drive. In the beginning, you have to log into Google Drive in order to be able to access it. This brings up the Google Login screen, first asking for email, then password, **then** (if 2FA is configured) for the code from the Google Authenticator app. If the user is doing that on a mobile device s/he has to leave the web app, open the authenticator app, retrieve the code and return to the web app.

My problem is now, that the web app will then reload and **lose the state** it was in so that the user has to start over with the login process and the code will most likely expire.

Because the app opens a the Google Login screen over which I have no control, I also can't restore the state manually.

Is there any way to prevent losing the state of the login process when leaving the web app?

Thanks all

Marc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PWA Application is initialized every time after going backgorund in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586797/pwa-application-is-initialized-every-time-after-going-backgorund-in-ios)

Comment: I wouldn't say so. That would be the case if we'd talk about a page in my own app. But in this case, the app opens a the Google Login screen over which I have no control, so I can't restore the state manually.